# Can an IP be considered as sensible and not disclosable information?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, isp

So my problem is this.

I reset my router by mistake, now I need the ip of the central hub of the building to set my router up. I contacted the responsible technician and he told me that as a matter of privacy he cannot tell me this ip (he says that being the common IP of all the router condominiums is a sensitive information) and he wants me to pay 130 euros for the "technical" intervention. i'm not buying this at all. Here are the possible questions (sorry for the one not related to software or hardware):
-Is this information really private by law?
-if I connect to a neighbor's router and I do a **traceroute** can I find this ip? If yes, it means that then it is not sensitive information.

Comment: It's not sensitive. Just go ask your neighbour what his gateway address is :)

Comment: It is just not an information they have or they know how to get,  do you think the traceroute is a viable solution?

Comment: Yeah, traceroute will give it as well. From their network.

Comment: The tech is a jerk.

Comment: Look at the contract to provide you with access to the Internet. Theoretically, information about the settings of your equipment (router) must be in it or must be attached to it.

Comment: Can an IP Address be sensitive information, it indeed can be, entirely depends on the mission of the computer network in question.  So the only real answer to your question is "it depends on the situation".

Comment: If the issue is that the information is confidential, it seems like disclosing it to you for a bribe would be a criminal act on his part.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this information really private by law?

It can be depending on the purpose and the type of network the IP address is in. But in this case it cannot really be private - your ISP technician just wants the extra money.

> If I connect to a neighbor's router and I do a traceroute can I find this ip? If yes, it means that then it is not sensitive information.

Yes, you can find the IP. And using `traceroute` is actually an overkill, you can simply check your gateway address with `ipconfig` on Windows or `route -n` / `ip r` on Linux if you're connected to a working network.
And yes, that is not sensitive information.

Comment: Imma try step this question up. I got the neighbors wifi and I did tracert https://ibb.co/vshYBwn and this is my router configuration https://ibb.co/NrRKsdF but i don0't really know what ip i have to put. The second seems to not work.                   I cannot argue with the technician because he can dewhitelist my router mac whenever he wants and then i could do nothing to get my internet back.