# I have two routers connected at the same hub, how can I set the one not working in the same way as the other?

Tags: networking, router, isp

The company that installed my condominium internet doesn't want to give me the information about the router configuration and wants me to pay 130 euro for the technical intervention.

I got the flatmate wi-fi but i cannot access the router configuration at 192.168.1.1 because they changed the standard password. I need to mimic the same configuration to my router.

I did a **traceroute** to get the gateway ip and this is my **router configuration interface** (Screenshot below). By trial and error it seems that I'm still missing some information.

```
 1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
 2   101 ms    73 ms    58 ms  172.16.0.2
 3    40 ms    39 ms    39 ms  FASTGATE [192.168.1.254]
 4    50 ms    52 ms    69 ms  10.5.3.98
 5   349 ms   306 ms   304 ms  10.250.137.174
 6    54 ms    49 ms    49 ms  10.251.155.194
 7    55 ms    53 ms    52 ms  10.254.20.45
 8    56 ms    56 ms    52 ms  93-63-100-105.ip27.fastwebnet.it [93.63.100.105]
 9    51 ms    53 ms    52 ms  93-63-100-182.ip27.fastwebnet.it [93.63.100.182]
 10    55 ms    54 ms    52 ms  72.14.204.46
 11    61 ms    57 ms    54 ms  108.170.245.81
 12    54 ms    54 ms    53 ms  108.170.233.143
 13    52 ms    53 ms    55 ms  dns.google [8.8.8.8]
```

[image: router configuration interface]
Every time i try a new configuration i get this error. https://ibb.co/xFSFsqz

PS: My router is already authorized in the network (its MAC was whitelisted upon installation and I’m paying for the internet service ). I’m just trying to bypass the technician that wants 130 euro to set up my router Again., The flatmate owning the working router (knowing the pretty sly situation) allowed me to brute force the username and password of the working router but I'm missing the username and it is not working.

Comment: Please copy the text of your traceroute as such. You can mark it as code (e.g. four space indention) to make it readable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you may have a "group MDU" setup by the ISP, if this is the case adding an unauthorized device would be considered stealing. And brute forcing a device you don't technically own will most certainly be against your TOS agreement. You should clear this up in the question, or it might get closed.

Comment: Ok, i’m not stealing from anyone. I’m just defending myself from unethical working practices.https://superuser.com/questions/1418272/can-an-ip-be-considered-as-sensible-and-not-disclosable-information?noredirect=1#comment2142017_1418272 This is the related question.

Comment: Start > cmd enter > "ipconfig /all" should reveal the local gateway when connected to the neighbors router.